# How to save client_id when navigate in another component, not with storage, using Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

To save the value when passing from one component to another, use this code:

Service.ts:

```
 _data = new Map<string, any>();
  setData(key, value) {
    this._data.set(key, value);
  }

  getData(key) {
    return this._data.get(key);
  }

  clear() {
    this._data = new Map<string, any>();
  }
```

Component.ts

```
  let client_id = '';
    if (this.ss.getData('client_id')) {
      client_id = this.ss.getData('client_id');
    }

  this.addsale = this.fb.group({
       ...
      'client_id': new FormControl(client_id, Validators.required),
      ....
    });

  saveData() {
   this.ss.setData('client_id', this.addsale.get('client_id').value);
  }
```

this code save me, client_name. like in image [image]:

In this part the problem is when I have more clients with this name.

How to save and client_id in this code?

Answer (score 0):

they are many way to keep  any value you want from component to other :

1.**use @input**
 2. **use service and put initil state and u can modifieded when 
   u navigate or any logic u want**
 3. **use params in Router**
 4.**use Store (Redux)**

Comment: I create this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9sijka-o1h2tp?file=app%2Fautocomplete-display-example.html  can you see please?

Comment: im really not understand ur problem where is ,if you use services to get ur client_id u must be careful where are u put  service (provider) to share reference in ur app.

Comment: its better to struct ur project put services in folder call services and models in folder models .... to make easy to read